# Getting PID of process from bash shell command invoked from MONO C# app

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, c#, mono-framework

I have following linux terminal command:

```
ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep 'TestService.exe' | awk '{print $2}'
```

which **works fine from Linux terminal** and retreives `PID` of wanted process, for example, output is: `5532`. However, I have to run upper command from `Mono C#` application using following code:

```
Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "/bin/bash",
        Arguments = string.Format("-c ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep '{0}' | awk '{{print $2}}'", p),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false
    }
};
```

which is (almost) identical to command,  **launched from terminal**, however, the output is:

```
testuser+   2184   2160  0 11:43 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/local/bin/mono-sgen /home/testuser/testuser/MONO/cs/src/testApp/bin/Debug/TestService.exe
```

but I need only `PID` column, i.e., **PID of a process**. Why is output different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `$`, like this

```
/bin/bash -c "ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep '{0}' | awk '{{print \$2}}'"
```

If you don't `$2` gets interpreted too early by the shell and it ends up like this:

```
/bin/bash -c "ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep '{0}' | awk '{{print}}'"
```

and this will just will print the entire input line