# Running a Bash script in Cygwin

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, shell, cygwin

Installed Cygwin, wrote my script, tested successfully. However when I go to run it as a Windows scheduled task it fails. Further digging is showing that not all programs are available when running the script in this manner. For example Launching Mintty and typing in `ls` will list the contents of my directory.

Running bash.exe from the Windows CLI will put me in a Bash prompt, but `ls` is not a recognized command.

I have tried the standard

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -l -c "/home/user/logoff.sh"
```

as well as the

```
c:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/bash -l -c "/home/user/logoff.sh"
```

I added an echo command that outputs to a text file, and that works so I know the script is getting called. The issue appears to either be with the various programs not being available, or it doesn't like the piping I am doing.

This is the script I am trying to run.

```
for user in user1 user2 user3 ;
do
id=$(query user $user 2>> /dev/null | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed -e '/ID/ d')
if [[ "$id" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]?$ ]]; then
logoff $id
echo "$user was logged off" >> logg_off.log
fi
done
```

Any ideas?

Here is some more information:

1. I fat fingered the file name in the scheduled task, which is why it failed to run.
2. Still not sure why the script would fail to finish. I removed all but one user from the list and everything works as expected. Will have to wait until this evening to test whether or not I can log off the other users in one pass.

Comment: try using the applications full paths in the script `/usr/bin/awk` and so on

Comment: When debugging, try to break down the script line by line to find the problem. You should be able to pinpoint the problem to a single line and go from there.

Comment: Try [escaping the $](https://superuser.com/a/1186485/337631)

Comment: Those are good steps to take. Will need to remember that the path may not include awk, grep, sed, etc and need to specify their locations.

Answer (score 1):

So after some more fiddling around I found that the session ID is removed when the user is disconnected. Instead of inserting a tab or similar as a place holder, it just inserts spaces.

So when Awk prints out the column is prints the wrong information. Below is the final script that runs as a scheduled job in Windows Server.

```
for user in user1 user2 user3 ;
do
id=$(query user $user 2>> /dev/null | awk '{ print $3 }' | sed -e '/ID/ d')
if [[ "$id" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]?$ ]]; then
logoff $id
date >> /cygdrive/c/log_off.log
echo "$user was logged off" >> /cygdrive/c/log_off.log
else
id2=$(query user $user 2>> /dev/null | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e '/SESSIONNAME/ d')
if [[ "$id2" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]?$ ]]; then
logoff $id2
date >> /cygdrive/c/log_off.log
echo "$user was logged off" >> /cygdrive/c/log_off.log
fi
fi
done
```